# Python CSV SQL rows not printing

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write to each columns the results of my queries, however when I run my below script it seems to format with the data not appearing in the column next to it displaying all the rows.

```
results = []
results2 = []
results3 = []
results4 = []
results5 = []
results6 = []

cur.execute(dbQuery)

results.extend(cur.fetchall())

cur.execute(dbQuery2)

results2.extend(cur.fetchall())

cur.execute(dbQuery3)

results3.extend(cur.fetchall())

cur.execute(dbQuery4)

results4.extend(cur.fetchall())

cur.execute(dbQuery5)

results5.extend(cur.fetchall())

cur.execute(dbQuery6)

results6.extend(cur.fetchall())


with open("out.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Query1', 'Query2', 'Query3', 'Query4', 'Query5', 'Query6'])
    csv_writer.writerow(results, results2, results3, results4, results5, results6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate the results of all the query, then you need to write the CSV file. I assumed all the results from DB like below.

```
import csv

results = [1,2,3,4]
results2 = [11,12,13,14]
results3 = [21,22,23,24]
results4 = [31,32,33,34]
results5 = [41,42,43,44]
results6 = [51,52,53,54]

with open('out.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Query1', 'Query2', 'Query3', 'Query4', 'Query5', 'Query6'])
    csv_writer.writerows(zip(*[results, results2, results3, results4, results5, results6]))
```

Comment: what is that zip you refer to?

Comment: Refer this link for zip    https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: This just prints one row, the queries are meant to have lots of rows 6 columns with 200ish rows each

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code. Try with this, it may help full.